# Issue with Text-Form-Field in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, input, textfield, textformfield

I want to change value input without typing. Example, I have two Text-Form-Field then I want when I type 1 in Text-Form-Field #1 so the value display in Text-Form-Field #2 is 2. I want to value change depend on value in other input then display it.

I am trying but not work. So how to solve this problem. Please help me !!!!!!!!!

Update: I solved this problem. Thank for everyone !!!

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update value of text field 2 in onChanged method of text field 1.

Example:-

```
TextFormField(
                controller: textController1,
                onChanged: (String? value){
                  textController2.text="new value";
                },
              ),
```

Comment: Glad to help you. Would really appreciate if you mark this answer as useful.

Comment: I have new problem. Can you help me?

Comment: Sure, Please elaborate.

Comment: How to create dropdown button with data is List<dynamic>. Example: [{"carName": "...", "image": "...."}] with both option and optionSelected display image and name. I have problem with optionSelected. And can you have any contact with you :))) facebook, discord, telegram or slack.

Comment: Can you please add your code here.

Comment: Too long code. I don't know how to add code here :). How to contact with you?

Answer (score 0):

For this task, using the `TextEditingController` along with the `onChanged` callback function of the TextFormField is recommended. The following example provides a clear illustration of the desired approach.

```
class TextFormFieldDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const TextFormFieldDemo({super.key});

  @override
  State<TextFormFieldDemo> createState() => _TextFormFieldDemoState();
}

class _TextFormFieldDemoState extends State<TextFormFieldDemo> {
  late final TextEditingController textField1Controller;
  late final TextEditingController textField2Controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textField1Controller = TextEditingController();
    textField2Controller = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textField1Controller.dispose();
    textField2Controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: textField1Controller,
            onChanged: (value) {
              final double? val = double.tryParse(value);
              if (val != null) {
                textField2Controller.text = (val + 1).toString();
              }
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 12),
          TextFormField(
            controller: textField2Controller,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply implement this with assigning same textEditingController to the both textFormField widget as below

```
class TextFormFieldDemo extends StatefulWidget {
          const TextFormFieldDemo({super.key});
        
          @override
          State<TextFormFieldDemo> createState() => _TextFormFieldDemoState();
}
        
class _TextFormFieldDemoState extends State<TextFormFieldDemo> {
          late final TextEditingController textFieldController=TextEditingController();
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(),
              body: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: textFieldController,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: textFieldController,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```